# Jumpy/laggy scrolling with Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nouveau

I need your help on an extremely irritating issue. I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 and i'm having many different issues with my Nvidia card, mostly tearing and jumpy/laggy performance. These problems occur for me on many different distros i tried, for example Xubuntu (default windows manager, Compton and Compiz), Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Opensuse and Manjaro.

And i think/saw that the culprit of these are Nvidia drivers.

I fixed tearing by adding { ForceCompositionPipeline = On } on my xorg.conf.

```
Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-0: 1920x1080_60 +1600+0 { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }, HDMI-0: 1600x900_60 +0+0 { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

What i can't fix is the jumpy/laggy/stuttering performance experienced almost everywhere but most evidently when smooth scrolling (clicking on the mouse wheel and then scrolling) on Firefox. Chromium, or Opera. Every few milliseconds, browser "'jumps" a few pixels. It's not much, but enough to destroy the experience. Interestingly, when disabling Nvidia's drivers and enabling Nouveau, this is fixed. But i guess this is not a "good" solution.

Anything i could try to fix this in Xubuntu?

Thanks in advance.

PS: This is my inxi -Fxv output:

```
System:    Host: djdblinux Kernel: 3.19.0-25-generic x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 4.8.2) 
Desktop: Xfce 4.11.8 (Gtk 2.24.23) Distro: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty
Machine:   Mobo: ASRock model: Z97 Extreme4 Bios: American Megatrends version: P1.30 date: 05/23/2014
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-4690K CPU (-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 27992.9 Clock Speeds: 1: 3899.218 MHz 2: 3899.902 MHz 3: 3928.886 MHz 4: 3896.894 MHz
**Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GK104 [GeForce GTX 770] bus-ID: 01:00.0 
X.Org: 1.17.1 driver: nvidia Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz, 1600x900@60.0hz  GLX Renderer: GeForce GTX 770/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 346.82 Direct  Rendering: Yes**
Audio:     Card-1: NVIDIA GK104 HDMI Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 01:00.1 
 Card-2: Texas Instruments PCM2902C Audio CODEC driver: USB Audio usb-ID: 001-006
Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture ver: k3.19.0-25-generic
 Network:   Card: Intel Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V driver: e1000e ver: 2.3.2-k port: f040 bus-ID: 00:19.0
IF: eth0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: d0:50:99:28:ed:16
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1128.3GB (0.6% used) 1: id: /dev/sda model: INTEL_SSDSC2CW12 size: 120.0GB temp: 0C 2: id: /dev/sdb model: WDC_WD10EZEX size: 1000.2GB temp: 44C 3: USB id: /dev/sdc model: v165w size: 8.0GB temp: 0C 
Partition: ID: / size: 103G used: 5.4G (6%) fs: ext4 ID: swap-1 size: 8.53GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap 
RAID:      No RAID devices detected - /proc/mdstat and md_mod kernel raid module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 46.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 0.0:44C 
Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A 
Info:      Processes: 203 Uptime: 17 min Memory: 856.3/7933.0MB Runlevel: 2 Gcc sys: 4.8.4 
Client: Shell (bash 4.3.11) inxi: 1.9.17
```